# Can't Shudras read the Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, vedanta, caste-system, shudra

It is well known that Vedanta Sutras prohibit Shudras from Jnana by saying Smritis prohibit them from having Upanayana. But Bhagavad Gita is a book which contains Vedantic statements. As Vedanta Sutras prohibit Shudras from acquiring Vedanta knowledge, can't they read the Bhagavad Gita?

Comment: Bhagavad Gita is basically the summary of the 4 Vedas along with being the glory of Krishna. So I think they can not

Comment: Mahabharata can be read by anyone. Bhagavad Gita is a part of Mahabharata and hence it is open for all.

Comment: Bhagavad Gita is a knowledge for all to realize their spiritual nature. No classification or restriction is there for Bhagavad Gita!

Comment: Akshay already answered.

Answer (score 12):

There are no specific restrictions for reading and understanding Bhagavad Gita based on castes, differentiation apart from two cases, where Krishna himself emphasizes on to whom this Gita knowledge should not be spoken and to whom this knowledge shall be revealed

> BG 18.67: This instruction should never be explained to those who are not austere or to those who are not devoted. It should also not be spoken to those who are averse to listening (to spiritual topics), and especially not to those who are envious of me.
>
> BG 18.68: Those, who teach this most confidential knowledge amongst my devotees, perform the greatest act of love. They will come to me without doubt.

Thus, from these verses, it is clear that, those who teach his Gita knowledge to his devotees, certainly reaches Krishna's abode which he himself declares and also the fact that, Sri Krishna makes it clear that this knowledge should not be explained to non-devotees, and non-believers of supreme because they may become envious of Krishna and misunderstand the teachings of Gita and think Krishna proudly spoke of himself and wanted Arjuna to praise him always as he used many times "I". So real meaning and teachings of Gita wont go into minds of non devotees.

Comment: Then why Vedanta is banned for Shudras? If a Shudra can read the Bhagavad Gita, he can also learn Vedanta,  since bhagavad Gita itself a summary of Upanishads.

Comment: Where is it written that vedanta is not  for shudra? And as per you who is shudras?

Comment: @NaveenKick  Because reading summary and reading the original is not the same. It was condensed into easy form as Bhagavad Gita.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma You are correct

Comment: @LoveSharma Have a look at here. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62931.html

Shudra is a person who belongs to fourth Varna, as the Smritis say.

Comment: @NaveenKick thanks for sharing link: in the same link it says chandogya claims that sudras are allow to read and brahma sutra says person with tamas guna or sudras are by guna itself do not read - not that from society it is enforced. The moment tamas guna develop rajas or sattva are automatically subscribe to knowledge. So their is no question of allow or disallow. The one who WANTS knowledge they are eligible. That’s it

Comment: The story of ravika... in that same link and at the end of para. @NaveenKick

Comment: No, you are misinformed. Read the 35th Sutra, which clearly says he was a Kshatriya.

Answer (score 8):

Mahabharata is composed by Vyasadeva so that all classes of people will benefit be it sudras, fallen brahmanas etc.. So they can definitely read Bhagavad Gita which is a part of Mahabharata.

> strī-śūdra-dvijabandhūnāṁ trayī na śruti-gocarā karma-śreyasi mūḍhānāṁ
>   śreya evaṁ bhaved iha iti bhāratam ākhyānaṁ kṛpayā muninā kṛtam
>
> [SB 1.4.25](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/4/25/): Out of compassion, the great sage thought it wise that
>   this would enable men to achieve the ultimate goal of life. Thus he
>   compiled the great historical narration called the Mahabharata for
>   women, laborers and friends of the twice-born.

Answer (score 5):

If for Mahabharata (of which Gita is a part) it is said that it can be recited by everyone then "Yes" will be the answer. But have a look at the following verses from Vyasa Smriti:

> Brahmanas, Kshatriyas, and Vaishyas are called the twice-born. Their
>   first births take place when they are delivered of their mother's womb
>   ; their second, when they duly accept the Gayatri Mantra from their
>   preceptors (21).
>
> **Thus made twice-born, and free from all other faults, they become entitled to study the Vedas, Smritis and Puranas (22).**

According to 22, it's the Vedic initiation that makes one qualified to read even the Smritis and the Puranas. So, we can assume that similar requirements might be there for reading the Itihasas too. Because, Itihasa-Purana are always mentioned in tandem.

Also, note that this is somewhat an indirect approach, as ideally one should see what Mahabharata itself( or Gita) has to say on the topic.

Comment: May be the 'sankalpita Gita paatha' is meant for twice borns only. Others can just read or listen to.

Comment: Yes may be not sure @ParthaBanerjee