# What is the eligibility for reciting shiva sahasranama stotram?

Tags: shiva, stotra

[Shiva Sahasranama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Sahasranama) is a "list of a thousand names" of Shiva, one of the most important deities in Hinduism.

Is there any eligibility for a person to recite it? If yes, what is the eligibility to do  stotram?

In short, who is eligible to recite Shiva sahasranama stotram?

Comment: "The" gives the impression that there is only one such Stotra but there are 4 from Itihasa-Purana only (AFAIK but may be more) and many more from the Tantras.. So I hv changed "The" to "A "..

Comment: @Rickross Okay,  but is there any difference in eligibility among them?

Comment: Well sahsranamas has Anga-Kara Nyasa which have Mantras (like Om, Swaha etc) .. so those portions  clearly can not be chanted by uninitiated people.. or Sudras... the answer does not take into consideration all that..

Comment: @Rickross Sorry I didn't see your comment. Can you re-edit this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mahabharata: Anushasana Parva, SECTION XVII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a017.htm)

> Upamanyu said
>
> These names [Shiva sahasranama] fraught with auspiciousness, leading to advancement, destructive of Rakshasas, and great cleansers should be imparted to only him that is devoted to the great Lord [Shiva], to him that has faith, to him that believes. Unto him that has no faith, him that is an unbeliever, him that has not subjugated his soul, it should never be communicated.

Comment: So if a Sudra or a Chandala is devoted to Lord Shiva can it be imparted to him?

Comment: That is what it implies from the passage. The devotion towards God will remove all the impurities @Rickross

Comment: @Rickross As this Shiva sahasranam version is part of Mahabharata so there seems no restriction for cast/gender. Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/30439/12304