# About slokha regarding Nala from Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, mantras, shloka, vyasa, nala

In **which chapter** of the Mahabharata the [following](http://neelastro.in/nala-damayanti/) shloka has been mentioned?

> The final benediction offered by Vedavyasa to the reader is this:
>
> **Karkotakasya nagasya damayantya nalasya cha**
>
> **Rtuparnasya rajarse kirttanam Kali nasanam**
>
> Think of the serpent King Karkotaka, of Damayanti and Nala and the
> Rajarishi (royal sage) Rituparna and be free from the shackles of Kali.

And does the above-mentioned shloka a **mantra or not**?

Is there any **eligibility** to chant it if it is a mantra?

If it is not a mantra, then how can it have **capability to destroy** Kali?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That verse appears to be from the [Kumbakonam Edition](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-03-itx.html) of the Southern Recension of the Mahābhārata:

> 3.77. adhyAyaH 077
>
> Mahabharata - Vana Parva - Chapter Topics
>
> > puShkaraM niShkAsitavatA nalena kuNDinapurAtsaputrAyA damayantyA AnayanapUrvakaM prajApAlanena sukhavAsaH .. 1 ..
> >
> > bR^ihadashvena dyudhiShThirAyAkShahR^idayavidyopadeshapUrvakaM saMkShepeNa harishchandropAkhyAnakathanam .. 2 ..
>
> Mahabharata - Vana Parva - Chapter Text
>
> > **karkoTakasya nAgas damayantyA nalasya cha**. 
> >     **R^ituparNasya rAjarSheH kIrtanaM kalinAshanam** .. 3-77-12

In the Critical Edition, [Ch. 63 of the Vana Parva](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/2_epic/mbh/mbh_03_u.htm), the verse is prefixed with a `*` meaning it's an interpolation:

> 03,063.001 bṛhadaśva uvāca
>   03,063.001a utsṛjya damayantīṃ tu nalo rājā viśāṃ pate
>   03,063.001c dadarśa dāvaṃ dahyantaṃ mahāntaṃ gahane vane
>   03,063.002a tatra śuśrāva madhye 'gnau śabdaṃ bhūtasya kasya cit
>   03,063.002c abhidhāva nalety uccaiḥ puṇyaśloketi cāsakṛt
>   03,063.003a mā bhair iti nalaś coktvā madhyam agneḥ praviśya tam
>   03,063.003c dadarśa nāgarājānaṃ śayānaṃ kuṇḍalīkṛtam
>   03,063.004a sa nāgaḥ prāñjalir bhūtvā vepamāno nalaṃ tadā
>   03,063.004c uvāca viddhi māṃ rājan nāgaṃ karkoṭakaṃ nṛpa
>   03,063.005a mayā pralabdho brahmarṣir anāgāḥ sumahātapāḥ
>   03,063.005c tena manyuparītena śapto 'smi manujādhipa
>   03,063.005d*0300_01 tiṣṭha tvaṃ sthāvara iva yāvad eva nalaḥ kva cit
>   03,063.005d*0300_02 ito netā hi tatra tvaṃ śāpān mokṣyasi matkṛtāt
>   03,063.006a tasya śāpān na śaknomi padād vicalituṃ padam
>   03,063.006c upadekṣyāmi te śreyas trātum arhati māṃ bhavān
>   03,063.007a sakhā ca te bhaviṣyāmi matsamo nāsti pannagaḥ
>   03,063.007c laghuś ca te bhaviṣyāmi śīghram ādāya gaccha mām
>   03,063.008a evam uktvā sa nāgendro babhūvāṅguṣṭhamātrakaḥ
>   03,063.008c taṃ gṛhītvā nalaḥ prāyād uddeśaṃ dāvavarjitam
>   03,063.009a ākāśadeśam āsādya vimuktaṃ kṛṣṇavartmanā
>   03,063.009c utsraṣṭukāmaṃ taṃ nāgaḥ punaḥ karkoṭako 'bravīt
>   03,063.010a padāni gaṇayan gaccha svāni naiṣadha kāni cit
>   03,063.010c tatra te 'haṃ mahārāja śreyo dhāsyāmi yat param
>   03,063.011a tataḥ saṃkhyātum ārabdham adaśad daśame pade
>   03,063.011c tasya daṣṭasya tad rūpaṃ kṣipram antaradhīyata
>   03,063.012a sa dṛṣṭvā vismitas tasthāv ātmānaṃ vikṛtaṃ nalaḥ
>   03,063.012c svarūpadhāriṇaṃ nāgaṃ dadarśa ca mahīpatiḥ
>   03,063.013a tataḥ karkoṭako nāgaḥ sāntvayan nalam abravīt
>   03,063.013c mayā te 'ntarhitaṃ rūpaṃ na tvā vidyur janā iti
>   03,063.013d`*`0301_01   **karkoṭakasya nāgasya damayantyā nalasya ca**
>   03,063.013d`*`0301_02   **ṛtuparṇasya rājarṣeḥ kīrtanaṃ kalināśanam**
>   03,063.014a yatkṛte cāsi vikṛto duḥkhena mahatā nala
>   03,063.014c viṣeṇa sa madīyena tvayi duḥkhaṃ nivatsyati
>   03,063.015a viṣeṇa saṃvṛtair gātrair yāvat tvāṃ na vimokṣyati
>   03,063.015c tāvat tvayi mahārāja duḥkhaṃ vai sa nivatsyati

K M Ganguli includes this verse in his [translation](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03079.htm) and clearly Sage Bṛhadaśva is referring to recitation of the entire story of Nala-Damayanti so I assume anyone can recite it (see [Can't Śūdras read the Bhagavad-gītā?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30433/2995)).

> Vrihadaswa said, '...And, O lord of the earth, Nala suffered such dire woe all alone and recovered his prosperity, whereas thou, O son of Pandu, with heart fixed on virtue, art sporting in joy in this great forest, accompanied by thy brothers and Krishna. When thou art also, O monarch, mixing daily with blessed Brahmanas versed in the Vedas and their branches, thou hast little cause for sorrow. **This history, besides, of the Naga Karkotaka, of Damayanti, of Nala and of that royal sage Rituparna, is destructive of evil.** And, O thou of unfading glory, this history, destructive of the influence of Kali, is capable, O king, of comforting persons like thee when they listen to it. And reflecting upon the uncertainty (of success) of human exertion, it behoveth thee not to joy or grieve at prosperity or adversity. Having listened to this history, be comforted, O king, and yield not to grief. It behoveth thee not, O great king, to pine under calamity. Indeed, men of self-possession, reflecting upon the caprice of destiny and the fruitlessness of exertion, never suffer themselves to be depressed. **They that will repeatedly recite this noble history of Nala, and that will hear it recited, will never be touched by adversity.** He that listeneth to this old and excellent history hath all his purposes crowned with success and, without doubt, obtaineth fame, besides sons and grandsons and animals, a high position among men, and health, and joy...'

So instead of making a mantra out of the verse and repeatedly chanting it, the focus should be on the story and the lessons it teaches.

Answer (score 1):

The slokas mentioned in Mahabharata are different, though the meaning is similar.

The [slokas](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs03078.htm) mentioned in [Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03079.htm) are as follows:

> 10 इतिहासम इमं चापि कलिनाशनम उच्यते
>        शक्यम आश्वासितुं शरुत्वा तवद्विधेन विशां पते
>
> 11 अस्थिरत्वं च संचिन्त्य पुरुषार्थस्य नित्यदा
>        तस्याये च वयये चैव समाश्वसिहि मा शुचः
>
> 12 ये चेदं कथयिष्यन्ति नलस्य चरितं महत
>        शरॊष्यन्ति चाप्य अभीक्ष्णं वै नालक्ष्मीस तान भजिष्यति
>
> 10 itihāsam imaṃ cāpi kalināśanam ucyate
>        śakyam āśvāsituṃ śrutvā tvadvidhena viśāṃ pate  11 asthiratvaṃ ca saṃcintya puruṣārthasya nityadā
>        tasyāye ca vyaye caiva samāśvasihi mā śucaḥ  12 ye cedaṃ kathayiṣyanti nalasya caritaṃ mahat
>        śroṣyanti cāpy abhīkṣṇaṃ vai nālakṣmīs tān bhajiṣyati
>        arthās tasyopapatsyante dhanyatāṃ ca gamiṣyati
>
> This history, besides, of the Naga Karkotaka, of Damayanti, of Nala
>   and of that royal sage Rituparna, is destructive of evil. And, O thou
>   of unfading glory, this history, destructive of the influence of Kali,
>   is capable, O king, of comforting persons like thee when they listen
>   to it. And reflecting upon the uncertainty (of success) of human
>   exertion, it behoveth thee not to joy or grieve at prosperity or
>   adversity.

---

The slokas mentioned by OP might have been composed by some other person.