# Qualification to read the puranas

Tags: puranas

Is there any qualification required to read the puranas.
can you please quote from hindu scriptures to prove your point.

Comment: As per the verses quoted in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/30436/4732), only Dvijas who have Upanayana are qualified. However, as per Puranas (apparently) even the non-dvijas are qualified.

Answer (score 1):

No and never it will be since we are reading purana's to understand our dharma better. Thus a person with 0 qualifications even if he has not uttered god's name a single time can read Purana's and is qualified to get the boons of it.

Currently I'm reading Shiv Puran in Hindi Published by Manoj Publications. It has a Beautiful story in Adhyay 1-5 ( Shiv Puran Mahatmay, the very first Adhyay's of the book) The story is of Maha Pishach Bindug and Chunchula who were the worst at their times. Bindug always did bad things, killed people and all with his wife chunchula who was a vaishya and all(you woll find this on internet easily). Of them Bindug died one day and went to Patal Lok Chunchula alone left on earth, one fine day she got chance to hear Shiv Puran from a Katha Going somewhere and due to this when the day came of she leaving earth, she entered Shivlok rather than Patal.

My only point is that today we are doing bad things but we are not as bad as Bindug and Chunchula who if we see their Karma's when they were in Earth never deserve to even look god himself who gets a chance of going to Shiv Lok. So its never that we need to be qualified to read a Puran, just have a pure mind.

Other thing if you want the Shiv Puran text book of Manoj Publication its available with me for free, I'll give you PDF where you can find the story I mentioned just drop your email in the comments.